# How do I create an infinite tower

Tags: c#, monogame, game-mechanics

So I had this idea of creating a 2D game where the player would just climb a tower the furthest he could.

[image]

I do already have a camera and a scene class somewhat ready, but I'm not sure how I would add the side sprites and make it so I dont use all the memory on the 10th update.
Could anyone please shed some light on this?

Comment: Hint: you only need what is visibile.

Comment: Hint: procedural sides roller, just vertical

Comment: When the player falls down, do you scroll down to show segments the player already passed before, or do you just kill the player when they hit the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

While the player ascends the tower, delete the tower sections below the camera viewport and generate new tower sections above the camera viewport.

Continuously allocating and deallocating memory might result in memory fragmentation, which could become a performance problem. Considering that your game idea seems rather light and simple, this might not actually be a real problem. But when it does become a problem, you can solve it by not discarding but reusing the deleted tower section. Move it from the bottom to the top and then use your generation algorithm to remodel it.

But now there is of course the question about what you do if the player decides to not move up but down the tower. In that case you would need a way to re-generate old tower sections in the same way the player saw them before.

Many games take the easy way out here and just don't allow the player to go back. The screen only ever scrolls up, and when the player-character crosses the lower edge of the screen, that's a lose-condition.

But if you don't want that, then you need a section generation algorithm which is deterministic. There are several approaches to this.

- Re-initialize your random number generator for each chunk. You can calculate those "chunk seeds" by determining a constant "run seed" at the beginning of each run, then create a hash value of the "run seed" plus the y-coordinate of the chunk you want to generate and use that as the "chunk seed". (But keep in mind that the first couple numbers generated by many random number generators right after seeding are of very low quality)
- Save the state of your RNG for each chunk you generated. That way you can restore the RNG to a prior state. The RNG states should consume a lot less memory than the chunks themselves (assuming your chunks aren't tiny).
- Generate the random input for each chunk by sampling a noise pattern. Here is a very interesting [GDC talk explaining this technique](https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1024365/Math-for-Game-Programmers-Noise).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways how i implement this behaviour on my games

**Using physics**

I would create big collider box at the bottom of the screen when this collider box touches the sprites in your case Vertical and horizontal walls it would destroy them.

**Pooling**

I would create a class which is responsible for registering and removing existing objects in my game.
In this case i would add register my sprites and destory them using a max distance parameter

**Example**

```
public class SpriteGarbageCollector
{
    public float removeDistance;
    private List<Object> _objects;
    private Player _targetPlayer;

    public SpriteGarbageCollector(Player player)
    {
        _targetPlayer = player;
    }

    public void Register(Object newObject)
    {
        _objects.Add(newObject);
    }
    public void Tick()
    {
        foreach(Object object in _objects)
        {
            if (removeDistance <= Distance(object, _targetPlayer))
            {
                Destroy(object);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These two way can provide you the garbage collection you need so you can just focus on your desing to how you should spawn your objects

Comment: This is a Unity3D answer to a MonoGame question, and would not provide any benefit since Unity3D `Destroy()` may? not remove private list references(especially during enumeration).

Comment: This is a general logic, which may be used in all contexes. IF you dont value the memory fragmentation then you can simply use it some algorithm like this.

Comment: `Destroy()` does not exist outside of Unity and therefor this answer is not applicable *outside* of  Unity and would be harmful to adapting this code to any other C# context where the only destruction is handled by the garbage collector.

Comment: Destroy is just a function, this is answer is applicable in every context out there. This post is about C# so it's handled by the garbage collector. Stop trying so hard to prove a point that does not exists. Destroy is not watermarked by Unity.